# Does USMLE Step 2 CS Annotation on B-1/B-2 visa restrict me from doing electives?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, study

I am a medical student. I am planning to go to the USA for my USMLE step 2 CS exam, and applied for a visa on this basis. My visa expires on 30 March 2019.

Recently, I got accepted in Electives Program at Cleveland Clinic, but I have annotation specifically for USMLE step 2 CS on my visa (but no duration) and now I have to take electives as well. I need to be in US for 5 months. I have two options: Should I inform the people at the Port of Entry about the electives, or is it a good idea to skip this information and hope that the officer would give a 6 month stay?

Comment: What happens if you skip the information and the officer doesn't give you six months?

Comment: Cannon Fodder, if I don't get 6 months, I will have to go back to my country, apply for a visa again, and come back to US (all that in a time span of 1 week)

Comment: You would have to explain why 5 months when you applied to go to the US for a one-day exam (and the clinical is a 4-week rotation).

Comment: Giorgio...No, actually I got accepted for 2 months rotations and 1 more month rotation is expected, so it more or less becomes 5 months.

Comment: What should be my plan of action on order to ensure a full 6-months stay

Answer (score 1):

Because you indicate there is no date next to the exam annotation, the immigration officer is almost definitely going to ask you how long you plan to stay before giving your duration of stay.

You will thus have an opportunity to tell him at that point. Should not be a problem. They by default give the six months and in the cases where they don’t, it’s after asking you questions on your purpose for the visit.

I had a similar annotation when I was coming to play in a tournament here many years ago.